# How to set headers in http get request?

Tags: http, go

I'm doing a simple http GET in Go:

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
res, _ := client.Do(req)
```

But I can't found a way to customize the request header in the [doc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), thanks

Answer (score 388, accepted):

The `Header` field of the Request is public. You may do this :

```
req.Header.Set("name", "value")
```

Answer (score 88):

Pay attention that in http.Request header "Host" can not be set via `Set` method

`req.Header.Set("Host", "domain.tld")`

but can be set directly:

`req.Host = "domain.tld"`:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://10.0.0.1/", nil)
if err != nil {
    ...
}

req.Host = "domain.tld"
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: life-saving answer !!

Comment: wtf It is great answer!!!!! host is blocking.

Answer (score 52):

If you want to set more than one header, this can be handy rather than writing set statements.

```
client := http.Client{}
req , err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    //Handle Error
}

req.Header = http.Header{
    "Host": {"www.host.com"},
    "Content-Type": {"application/json"},
    "Authorization": {"Bearer Token"},
}

res , err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    //Handle Error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go's net/http package has many [functions that deal with headers](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header). Among them are [Add](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Add), [Del](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Del), [Get](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Get) and [Set](https://godoc.org/net/http#Header.Set) methods. The way to use Set is:

```
func yourHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("header_name", "header_value")
}
```

Comment: what type is w ?

Comment: @EswarYaganti how are you sending the headers? You get a `r *http.Request` and returns back something in  `w http.ResponseWriter`. So probably because you are returning headers, you need to write them in a response writer. And `w` is a response writer. Does this look logical to you?

Comment: The original poster said he wants to "customize the *request* header".  Your example customizes the *response* header.