# append username and password in http request in golang

Tags: http, go, restful-authentication, beego

what i have tried till now is like
and http request formed now is:`curl  -X POST http://localhost:8080/v1.0`

```
l_httpClient_ptr := http.Client{
  Timeout: timeout,
 }
 var l_resp_ptr *http.Response
 var l_resp_byte []byte
 l_resp_ptr, r_err = l_httpClient_ptr.Post(p_url_str, "text/xml; charset=utf-8", bytes.NewBufferString(p_request_str))

 l_resp_byte, r_err = ioutil.ReadAll(l_resp_ptr.Body)
 l_resp_ptr.Body.Close()
 r_response_str = string(l_resp_byte)

 return
}
```

Here I am able to send only request xml along with URL.
And with my code I don't know how to send Username and password along with url that is it should be like following URL:

```
curl -H "ChannelName: guest" -H "ChannelPassword: guest" -X POST http://localhost:8080/v1.0/
```

Comment: To echo @JimB, use the http package: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.SetBasicAuth

Comment: @JimB,can you please explain what should i need to add in this code to send only Username and password along with http request

Comment: @william.taylor.09          l_httpClient_ptr.Post(p_url_str, "text/xml; charset=utf-8", bytes.NewBufferString(p_request_str)) using this i can only send normal http request but i need to send Username and password also like i have mentioned in my question

Comment: See here how to set headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540219/set-headers-for-request-using-http-client-and-http-transport

Answer (score 0):

You can create a request with custom headers,like this:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", p_url_str, bytes.NewBufferString(p_request_str))
req.Header.Set("ChannelName", "guest")
req.Header.Set("ChannelPassword", "guest")
```

then execute this request with:

```
l_resp_byte, r_err := l_httpClient_ptr.Do(req)
```