# How can I add extra headers to http.Request for tracing issues

Tags: go, http.client

In golang, it seems no hook methods exist for `http.client`, so I'm wondering how can I add extra headers like `trace-id: xxx` in framework.

Ideal code is like below:

```golang
// this func add a hook method to http-client to rewrite header
client := buildWithRewriteHeaderHook()
//customRequest has no `trace-id`
client.Do(customRequest)
// remote server get trace-id from http headers
...
```

PS: I know how to add headers to a request by 'req.setHeader()', and in my opinion it's not a duplicate question to this one.  [How to set headers in http get request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864302/how-to-set-headers-in-http-get-request)

Comment: The "hook" is the Transport field. You can easily write your own RoundTripper that wraps http.DefaultTransport, for instance.

Comment: @Abdullah No, it's not. I cannot hack building custom request, cos it's out of my control. It might be an option to hack http.client.

Comment: @Peter According to the official doc, it's not safe. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper  . quote: RoundTrip should not modify the request, except for consuming and closing the Request's Body. RoundTrip may read fields of the request in a separate goroutine.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that. At my workplace we wrap the whole client, actually. The Do method is all you need to send requets, so you can declare your own one-method interface which lends itself nicely to composition. You can take a look at [our package](https://godoc.org/github.com/classmarkets/cmhttp#WithHeader) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I should forget about the manual as long as it works in my scene.

Answer (score 0):

You should use headers.

You can do:

```golang
r.Header.Add("trace-id", "yourid")
```

You can also use open source package such as the opentracing one, which follows open tracing conventions and has method to add and read tracing information from requests: https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go